# How to set color using attr.xml?

Tags: java, android, xml

I want to do this:

```
textView.setTextColor(R.attr.myColor)
```

This is because I created a custom color for both night mode and light mode

```
attr.xml
<resources>
    <attr name="myColor" format="reference|color" />

themes.xml
      <item name="textMessageColor">@color/black</item>

themes-night.xml
  <item name="textMessageColor">@color/white</item>
```

But whenever I use it, it does not work.

Comment: your error occure is this java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Cant convert to color: type=0x2  right..?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17700862/custom-attr-get-color-returns-invalid-values

Check this link. It might be helpful.

Comment: @BADSHAH Thank you, but i didn't get such error. Chandan kushwaha Thanks i will try your suggestion

Comment: Ok, no Problem bro

Answer (score 0):

Try this in xml like
`<TextView`
`android:id="@+id/textView"`
`android:layout_width="match_parent"`
`android:layout_height="wrap_content"`
`android:textColor="?myColor"/>`

Comment: thanks but i need it in java for a ui component

Comment: For UI component you can use
textView.setTextColor(getThemeAttrColor(YourActivity.this, R.attr.myColor));